# How to delete a key using HDEL if the key have space with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, redis-cli

I am using Ruby 2.5.1 and trying to delete keys from redis using [HDEL](https://redis.io/commands/hdel). But it doesn't work key with spaces. I can delete with the quotes from redis-cli but I need to write a code to delete keys with space.

Sample value

> ["play group_1", "{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Play Group\"}"]

Delete not working in redis-cli (If doesn't passing single quotes with in it),

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HDEL development_groups play group_1
(integer) 0
```

Delete works in redis-cli (If passing single quotes with in it),

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HDEL development_groups 'play group_1'
(integer) 1
```

Ruby code,

> redis.hdel(index, key)

How to delete keys with space using [HDEL](https://redis.io/commands/hdel)?

Comment: To ask the obvious, have you tried passing the key in single quotes from your Ruby code?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it passing this "'play group_1'" 
my code,
 redis.hdel(index, "\'" + key+ "\'")

Comment: You should check the documentation for the Redis API which you are using with Ruby.  This is the first place to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with to_s option

i.e) key.to_s